# CSS3+Javascript position sticky scrollable with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a sidebar with the help of `position: sticky` and it works great.

Please see the script below for color identification with the following text.

As the black area scrolls down, the green area sticks put to it's sticky position with respect to the red topbar. But the green area is has content that overflows page's viewport.

As scroll reach near the page's end, i.e exactly when the height of overflown green area is equal to the height of the remaining scroll in the page, the green area starts to move.

But I want to move the green area to scroll along with the black area, and stay put when it reached it's end. Means, when the height of the sidebar is larger than the viewport, the sidebar should scroll at the window's scroll direction before getting affixed. (In-Short: I want it to move like facebook's side bar or something like this https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/examples/scrollable-element.html)

Is that even possible with `position:sticky`? With a little help with javascript and jquery?

I don't wan't to go with old `position:fixed` like few other libs out there when `position:sticky` is here!

```css
* {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

.topbar {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #D16666;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sidebar {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 60px;
  height: 1000px;
  line-height: 1000px;
  background: #B6C649;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}


.main-content {
  height: 1800px;
  line-height: 1800px;
  background: #2C4251;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}

.col-8 {
  top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://static.aftertutor.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">Topbar</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove position: sticky; from sidebar.

Comment: @GhitaB You mean?

Comment: I understand you want only topbar to be sticky. Right?

Comment: please check: https://youtu.be/U6gUqBzwu4Y

Comment: NO that is not what I am looking for. https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/ - Check this out. I need something similar to this with sticky.

Comment: No, I want both topbar and sidebar to be. But when the height of the sidebar is larger than the viewport, the sidebar should scroll at the window's scroll direction before getting affixed. @Mr.x

Comment: @Sibidharan Why you don't use that? abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/

Comment: @Mr.x - My requirement is highly dynamic and abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/  doesn't work with dynamic contents.

Comment: @Sibidharan Check this out [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmgg4on4/) something like this?

Comment: @Mr.x Not working as expected

Comment: @Mr.x This is what I am looking for https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/examples/scrollable-element.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a top position for the sidebar that is the amount of space that you allow it to go upwards.

A little javascript funcion can calculate this easily:

```js
function set ()  {
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    var sidebarHeight = sidebar.clientHeight;
    var availableHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var sidebarTop =  availableHeight - sidebarHeight - 20;
    // 20px is the amount of space that will be left under the bottom of the sidebar
    // at the sticky position
    sidebar.style.top = sidebarTop + "px";
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

.topbar {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #D16666;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sidebar {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 60px;
  height: 1000px;
  line-height: 1000px;
  background: #B6C649;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}


.main-content {
  height: 1800px;
  line-height: 1800px;
  background: #2C4251;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}

.col-8 {
  top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://static.aftertutor.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">Topbar</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="set();">click me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

It does exactly what it should do. You have box with height of 1800px and sticky element with height 1000px. It is sticky until it reaches bottom of relative parent box. Sticky should switch to relative. You simulates fixed element.

EDIT: removed incorrect and misleading snippet, ad comments

Comment: See, when the main content scrolls, the side bar also have to scroll and get affixed when it reaches its end. At any part of the scroll when the main content changes its scroll direction, the sidebar should travel along.

Comment: Ok. I got it however I think that sticky has different behaviour than you expect. It would be much easier with fixed + scrollable view + piece of JS. You can even achieve different scroll speeds this way...

Comment: that is not what i asked for